# How could i create a XML file using my java object and set the specific format for this XML file?

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, sax

I have to create an XML file from java object with specific format of my XML file.

My xml should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person
            name="Nick"
            birthday = "09.03.1814"/>
</persons>
```

Or like this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person surname="Sd" name="aaa" birthday = "09.03.1814"/>
</persons>
```

Depends on old format of xml. How could i do this?
Thanks!

I've try to use this code for creating xml

```
public static void createNewXml(List<Person> persons) {
    List<DtoPerson> dtoPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person person : persons) {
        dtoPersonList.add(new DtoPerson(person));
    }
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext =  JAXBContext.newInstance(DtoPerson.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        File file = new File("personx.xml");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        for(DtoPerson personDto : dtoPersonList) {
            marshaller.marshal(personDto, file);
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dtoPersonList.toArray()));
}
```

But this code create an xml with other format

```
<dtoPerson>
    <birthday>09.03.1814</birthday>
    <name>aaa Sd</name>
</dtoPerson>
```

Comment: Please show code of  DtoPerson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add annotation @XmlAttribute to affected fields in DtoPerson.

Comment: Another question, how could i add main attribute? Like <persons>some person <persons/> . In first example you could see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create a Persons class containing a List<Person> attribute.